# Perl "Global symbol"

Tags: perl

In the following perl script,

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use Env;
use strict;
use warnings;
my $oscar_file = "input/oscar_single_piminus_1k.input";
my $PISAEvent_file  = "output/PISAEvent_piminus_1k.root";
my %pisa_input = "pisa_piminus_1k.input" ;
my %pisa_start = "pisa < pisa_piminus_1k.input";
my $nevents = 1000;
open(INPUT, ">" . $pisa_input);
print INPUT "0\nN\n0\n";
close(INPUT);
open(INPUT2,">glogon.kmac");
print INPUT2 "macro glogon.kumac\npisafile $PISAEvent_file\ntext_file $oscar_file -1 1\nptrig $nevents\nexit\nreturn\n";
close(INPUT2);
my $ret = system($pisa_start);
```

It returns the following error,

```
Global symbol "$pisa_input" requires explicit package name at pisa.pl line 26.
Global symbol "$pisa_start" requires explicit package name at pisa.pl line 32.
Execution of pisa.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Commenting out "use strict" does not help,

```
Name "main::pisa_input" used only once: possible typo at pisa.pl line 26.
Name "main::pisa_start" used only once: possible typo at pisa.pl line 32.
Odd number of elements in hash assignment at pisa.pl line 15.
Odd number of elements in hash assignment at pisa.pl line 20.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at pisa.pl line 26.
print() on closed filehandle INPUT at pisa.pl line 27.
Use of uninitialized value in system at pisa.pl line 32.
```

What is going on?

Comment: I just want to point out this line from the OP:  "Commenting out "use strict" does not help" - *facepalm* unfortunately I don't really know how to explain the problem with that constructively.  But someone should, just saying.

Comment: My car had developed a fault. I was out of control, careering down the hill in my car to certain death. Even removing my seat belt didn't help.

Comment: I burn things a lot while cooking and the fire alarm in the hall is really annoying, so I got rid of it.  Doesn't seem to help my cooking tho...

Comment: You guys are having fun, huh?

Comment: Hopefully we can amass a few dozen of these ;P

Comment: @mj_:  Hopefully in good fun :) but there's a serious point here that I don't know how to make besides via these silly jokes.  using strict only stops you from hurting yourself, it never stops you from doing something you actually want to do...  but I don't really know how to explain that beyond making silly jokes.

Comment: @goldilocks I am reminded of the Simpsons episode where Homer "fixes" his car problems by putting a piece of tape over the warning light.

Comment: thank you guys for the responses, i know i was abusing whe n i wrote this question, but at least i fixed the silly problem and some new stuff, considering this was the  first time i touched perl in my life... Now I need a donut...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`my %pisa_start = "pisa < pisa_piminus_1k.input";`

`my $ret = system($pisa_start);`

`%` v. `$`.

Those are the two lines you used that are not agreeing with each other.  If it still doesn't look wrong to you, go read your favorite Perl tutorial on variables.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't declare `$pisa_input` anywhere, and you're using a hashmap named the same (`%pisa_input`).

You probably meant:

```
my $pisa_input = "pisa_piminus_1k.input" ;
my $pisa_start = "pisa < pisa_piminus_1k.input";
```