# how can i split numbers using comma in a list in perl regular expression

Tags: perl

I have a list like

```
1,2,3
11,12,14
1,6,8
```

How should I split these numbers into

```
1
2
3
11
12
14
1
6
8
```

I tried

```
@num=(1,2,3
      11,12,14
      1,6,8);
$splitnum=$splitnum.','.$num;
```

but it didn't works. Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: `it didn't work` is a very poor error description, so never use it unless you elaborate.

Comment: Add some error messages you are getting.Also `use strict; use warnings;`

Answer (score 5):

You must be thinking of another language, because that assignment will cause a syntax error in perl. You can fix it easily by quoting your strings.

```
my @num = ("1,2,3",
           "11,12,14",
           "1,6,8");
```

I have no idea what your other line means, but it is wrong nonetheless. `$num` and `@num` are two different variables in perl, and have nothing to do with each other.

What you can do is this:

```
@num = map split(/,/), @num;
```

`map` will split each line in `@num` on the comma and return the list.

You should always put

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

In all your perl scripts. There will be errors, but they will teach you to avoid mistakes. Not using them is a Very Bad Idea, it is like protecting your head by wearing a blindfold instead of putting on a helmet.

Comment: Good answer and I like the analogy. I might use it in the future.

Comment: @flesk It was inspired from a comment thread on another question a few weeks ago. http://stackoverflow.com/q/10806269/725418

Comment: @flesk Borodin's reminded me of [another programming joke](http://www.jokecenter.com/jokes/Misc/458.htm)

Comment: @TLP `$num @num` are the names of variables in `$calar table` and `@rray table`, yeah :) why are you not using `map{split/,/}@num`? i don't think, that these two ways of using `map` is obvious for begginer, but my example is more simple to read. only my opinion.

Comment: @loldop Hah, I never realized before that the sigills are a mnemonic for themselves.. `$` looks like `S` and `@` like `a`. Good one. :) Wonder if `%` is meant to look like `H`. I prefer to use `map`, `grep` and similar commands without the curly braces if I can. I just think it looks cleaner that way. Just look at this windoze autoglobbing line: `@ARGV = map glob, @ARGV`. Looks sleek.

Comment: @TLP i think, that `%` means `cell to cell` :) thats looks like what it means, hash have `cell-key to cell-value`. hmm.. i know, that curly brackets mean an anonymous function and it is my space for code =)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `split` splits string(and not array) and returns list.
So your code should be.

```
my $str1="1,2,3,11,12,14,1,6,8"; 

my @num=split ',',$str1;

my $str2=join ' ',@num;

print $str2;
```

Or

You can use regex also `$str=~s/,/ /gm`;

Comment: <pedant>`split` returns a list, not an array</pedant>